# Spring Hibernate transaction - read only vs read write

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, transactions

I am facing a weird problem with Spring Boot(2.3.7) + PostgreSQL v12 (row level security) + Hibernate (5.x).

Here are the steps that I am executing

1. A procedure accepts an input variable and creates temporary table. The variable is then inserted in temporary table.
2. Spring Advice which executes for all `@Service` annotation and invokes a procedure with a variable (call it `custom_id`).
3. `@Transactional` attribute is specified on all `@Service` classes.
4. PostgreSQL row level security has been enabled on the tables being queried and updated.
5. Row level security applies filter based on the variable stored (`custom_id` value) in temporary table.
6. All update, select, insert operations are executed using custom implementation of `JpaRepository` (interface based)

This works fine as long as there are only select operation performed on the database. But starts to fail with code having a combination of select and updates. The code simply fails with a message as it is not able to locate the temporary table.

I enabled trace for Spring transaction and found that there are few statements like

> No need to create transaction for XXX

While code that performs update operation has statements like

> Getting transaction for XXX

After searching for a while, I realised that `SimpleJpaRepository` has `@Transaction` with `readonly` flag set to `true`. This results in SELECT operation getting executing in transaction less mode.

**Procedure**

```sql
create or replace procedure proc_context(dummy_id uuid) AS $context_var$
declare

begin

create temp table if not exists context_metadata
(
dummy_id uuid
)
on commit drop;

insert into context_metadata values(dummy_id);

end;
$context_var$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**ERROR**

Following error is logged in console

```
ERROR: relation "context_metadata" does not exist
```

**What I tried**

1. Tried implementing custom transaction manager and explicitly invoking the procedure to set the temporary variable value (Didn't work). Refer below

```java
    protected void prepareSynchronization(DefaultTransactionStatus status, TransactionDefinition definition) {

    super.prepareSynchronization(status, definition);

    if (status.isNewTransaction() || status.isReadOnly() || status.isNewSynchronization()) {

    UUID someID = ....;

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL proc_context(?);");

    query.setParameter(1, someID);

    query.executeUpdate();

    }

    }
```

2. Tried setting `@Transactional` notation with `readonly` set to `false` on all repositories.

**What I am looking for?**

Unfortunately due to this behaviour, the row-level security implementation is not working in my code. Is there any way to disable read-only transactions using a global property OR provide me with any hint to overcome this problem?

Comment: It won't run without a transaction it will run in a readonly transaction. The readonly part is only a hint for hibernate to omit the dirty checking. Also if there already is a transaction (which should be the case as you state yourself you annotated your services with `@Transactional` then it shouldn't matter as there is already an ongoing transaction).

Comment: That is where I am getting lost. I could figure out from logs that there is only one transaction and the code to create/populate temporary table is being executed. The update query simply fails complaining the temporary table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could figure out after 2 days of battle. The problem was multi-faceted.

1. I noticed `hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion` property set to true in application.properties file. I had to remove that property.
2. Developer had written a very messy code to update the entity attributes (Was performing select, then creating new instance, populating attributes and then calling save method). All this ruckus to update one single attribute.

Tested the code and everything worked fine.